# How to open the iPhone calendar from within my app?

Tags: iphone, calendar

I want to be able to implement a button in my app, that quits my app, and takes the user to the iPhone's calendar.
I'm not interested in sending the user to a specific event. Just opening up the calendar would do the trick.
Any suggestions?

Comment: its possible now....as the stone age is over....:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments on [this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html) blog post, there is currently no way to launch the calendar app.

Comment: Bummer. I have seen that blog, but hoped that there would be someone around here who knew better. I leave this question unanswered for now, hoping for more input

Answer (score 12):

Hey might be a late answer but you can do it now like this

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
```

Comment: Great little tip, not sure I'll use it, but it's little things like this that make SO so good - Thanks @iphonemaclover!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the Event Kit. It allows working with calendar
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Yeah, Event Kit is great, but: it only works on iOS4 , and there are still some limitations. You can't (yet) create a new calendar for example. But it looks promising.