# Open iphone calendar app programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calendar

I'd like to open the iphone calendar app programmatically from within my app. According to this post: [How to open the iPhone calendar from within my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889545/how-to-open-the-iphone-calendar-from-within-my-app) it isn't possible (May 22 2010!). Maybe the ios sdk 4 or ios sdk 5 support such a feature?

Comment: you can look @ this link, hope this will help you   http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/pmcalendar

Comment: put this code where you want open iOS calendar [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, except for using `UIDocumentInteractionController` with an .ical file, but that's pretty pointless as you could achieve the same (adding an event) by using [Event Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I guess you're right... I also found the Apple URL Scheme Reference which did not mentioned the calendar.

Answer (score 3):

use this line to open ios calendar :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
```

Comment: `calshow:t` where `t` is a number obtained with: `nsDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`