# how to launch iPhone Calendar from within an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, eventkit

Is it possible, and how could I, launch the iPhone calendar application from within an iPhone application.

For example your application may have a "select date", and then a "launch iPhone calendar" for this date button.  Is this possible to do, and how would one do this programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open iphone calendar app programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647725/open-iphone-calendar-app-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer seems to be, that at this stage, there are no published URLs for Calendar that lets you do this...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not a real answer. But I advise you to use a UIDatePicker to let the user select dates. I don't know if there's a offical way to start the calender. But you could also use the [Tapku Library](http://tapku.com/) of [Kal](https://github.com/briancollins/Kal) if you really want to use a calender. There's a replacement of the Calender UI which is used in iOS. (Because these elements aren't public)