# How to add event in native IOS Calendar

Tags: ios, icalendar, uidocumentinteraction

I want to open native IOS calendar(ical) from my application and add event. 
Is there any way i can open calendar for particular event?

I also follow [Open iphone calendar app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647725/open-iphone-calendar-app-programmatically) but not yet succeeded.

Comment: `SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.apple.mobilecal"), false);`, but it's private.

Comment: @AkshayCan you tell me which library or sample application you have referred to display native IOS calender?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See the [Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). But the basic process is:

1. Add the `EventKit.Framework` and `EventKitUI.Framework` to your project. (See [Linking to a Library or Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html).)
2. Import the header:

   ```
   #import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>
   ```
3. If creating an event, you use :

   ```
   - (IBAction)didPressCreateEventButton:(id)sender
   {
       EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

       if([store respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
       {
           // iOS 6
           [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent
                                 completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                     if (granted)
                                     {
                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                             [self createEventAndPresentViewController:store];
                                         });
                                     }
                                 }];
       } else
       {
           // iOS 5
           [self createEventAndPresentViewController:store];
       }
   }

   - (void)createEventAndPresentViewController:(EKEventStore *)store
   {
       EKEvent *event = [self findOrCreateEvent:store];

       EKEventEditViewController *controller = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
       controller.event = event;
       controller.eventStore = store;
       controller.editViewDelegate = self;

       [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
   ```
4. Your view controller should conform to the `EKEventEditViewDelegate` protocol:

   ```
   @interface ViewController () <EKEventEditViewDelegate>
   ```

   and implement the `didCompleteWithAction` method:

   ```
   - (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action
   {
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }
   ```
5. You can obviously create your event any way you want. For example, this is looks for an event in the next week with the appropriate title, and if it doesn't find it, create a new event (hour long event that starts in four hours):

   ```
   - (EKEvent *)findOrCreateEvent:(EKEventStore *)store
   {
       NSString *title = @"My event title";

       // try to find an event

       EKEvent *event = [self findEventWithTitle:title inEventStore:store];

       // if found, use it

       if (event)
           return event;

       // if not, let's create new event

       event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];

       event.title = title;
       event.notes = @"My event notes";
       event.location = @"My event location";
       event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];

       NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
       NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
       components.hour = 4;
       event.startDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components
                                                   toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                  options:0];
       components.hour = 1;
       event.endDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components
                                                 toDate:event.startDate
                                                options:0];

       return event;
   }

   - (EKEvent *)findEventWithTitle:(NSString *)title inEventStore:(EKEventStore *)store
   {
       // Get the appropriate calendar
       NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

       // Create the start range date components
       NSDateComponents *oneDayAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
       oneDayAgoComponents.day = -1;
       NSDate *oneDayAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDayAgoComponents
                                                     toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                    options:0];

       // Create the end range date components
       NSDateComponents *oneWeekFromNowComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
       oneWeekFromNowComponents.day = 7;
       NSDate *oneWeekFromNow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneWeekFromNowComponents
                                                          toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                         options:0];

       // Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
       NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:oneDayAgo
                                                               endDate:oneWeekFromNow
                                                             calendars:nil];

       // Fetch all events that match the predicate
       NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

       for (EKEvent *event in events)
       {
           if ([title isEqualToString:event.title])
           {
               return event;
           }
       }

       return nil;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you rob. Though i am not able to open calendar app directly still you solution is close to what I needed.

Comment: Thanks alots, its working fine me, i just copy and paste as its.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a very good code for native calender

Answer (score 10):

Use url scheme to open the native calender app.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
```

http://devsupport.layar.com/entries/23687993-How-to-use-Custom-URI-Scheme-Button-in-the-Creator-

Comment: hi. your solution works perfectly for iOS 7 but, its not working when i tried in an iOS 6.1 simulator. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: It will not work on 6.x simulator as 6.x simulator does not have a calender app in it. Try on device.

Answer (score 3):

The below code helps in adding events to native calendar.

```
- (NSString*)addEventToCalendarWithTitle:(NSString *)eventTitlestr Description:(NSString *)eventDescriptionstr startDate:(NSString *)startDatestr startTime:(NSString *)startTimestr {
        NSString *returneventidentifier=nil;
        if (__IPHONE_4_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED) {
                NSDateFormatter *formatter_=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                NSTimeZone *gmtZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
                NSDate *startedDate=nil;
                NSDate *endedDate=nil;
                [formatter_ setTimeZone:gmtZone];
                NSLocale *enLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];
                formatter_.locale = enLocale;
                [enLocale release];
                if (startDatestr!=nil&&startTimestr!=nil) {
                        startDatestr = [startDatestr stringByAppendingString:startTimestr];
                    }
                [formatter_ setDateFormat:[DATE_FORMAT_FROM_RESPONSE stringByAppendingString:TIME_FORMAT_FROM_RESPONSE]]; // here date and time formats are appended as datestring and time string are appended
                if(startDatestr!=nil){
                        
                        startedDate = [formatter_ dateFromString:startDatestr];
                        EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
                        //            __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
                        //            if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
                        //                dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
                        //                [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                        //                    accessGranted = granted;
                        //                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
                        //                }];
                        //                dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
                        //            } else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
                        //                accessGranted = YES;
                        //            }
                        //            
                        //            if (accessGranted) {
                        //            }
                        EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
                        event.title     = eventTitlestr;
            event.notes = eventDescriptionstr;
                        event.startDate = startedDate;
                        endedDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];
                        event.endDate   =endedDate ;
                        event.alarms=[NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:DEFAULTALERTTIME]];
                        [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                        NSError *err;
                        [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];  
                        [eventStore release];
                        eventStore=nil;
                        [endedDate release];
                        endedDate=nil;
                        returneventidentifier=event.eventIdentifier;
                    }
                [formatter_ release];
                formatter_=nil;
                
            }
        else {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert !" message:@"Lower IOS versions event adding functionality is not possible." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
            }
        return returneventidentifier;
}
```