# Add a "Add Event" Page in your iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I was wondering is there a way to add the following Add event screen to your iOS app, without actually creating it yourself, something like a method [show UIAddEvent].

Please let me know if there is way to do this.

[Click to see Add Event Screen Image](http://blog.laptopmag.com/wpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ios7_calendar_addevent-225x400.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar

Comment: I understand how to  anadd event programatically, but I'm looking for a way to get this native add event screen without actually creating it myself

Comment: I'm not sure but.. 95% my answer is "NO".. :(

Comment: take a look this might be helps to you [How to open native IOS calendar from my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742231/how-to-open-native-ios-calendar-from-my-app)

Comment: @iPatel this is Possible since iOS4 :) and user2603567 ignore thx and welcome as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [EventKitUI framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EventKitUIFrameworkRef/_index.html).
EKEventEditViewController is probably what you are looking for. The [SimpleEKDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/SimpleEKDemo.zip) sample on the developer site should get you started.

Comment: @Viruss mca ignore minor editing answer this is not a good you will be block by site.

Comment: @NitinGohel: ok i'll remember it.