# How to open default iOS calendar within my app?

Tags: events, ios7, calendar

How can I open default Calendar app with in my application? Currently I am accessing it using the following link but I am unable to back to my app.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
```

Comment: Check this already discussed [question][1]..

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742231/how-to-open-native-ios-calendar-from-my-app

Comment: hmm, I already went through but did not find a method / idea to get back to my app after open the calendar.

Comment: Whenever you are invoking any native app then you dont get navigation back..

Comment: Okay, Can you give me an idea to replicate the default Calendar im my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can find on this [site](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) useful layout in order to replicate default Calendar app appearance inside your application. There's also this [project](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal), in the end you can find a [SimpleEKDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160) on Event Kit reference on developer.apple.com that uses native components.