# How to open native calendar app from our app in iOS 6.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6.1

I have tried to open the native `iOS` **calendar app** from within my app using the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
```

The above code works perfectly in `iOS 7` and I am able to view my calendar app,
but, the code does not work in an `iOS 6.1` *simulator*.

I guess it is not supported in `iOS 6.1`.
Please do provide any suggestions or workarounds for this.
Thanks !

*PS: Yes, I'm aware of the features of the EventKit(UI) frameworks. But I'd like to specifically open the iCal app.*
*and*
*Yes I went through the 
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742231/how-to-open-native-ios-calendar-from-my-app).*

Comment: that because iOS 6.1 simulator not have calendar app. :)

Comment: why don't you test in on device and check??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simulator doesn't have a Calendar app. You can only do it on actual device.

Comment: Simulator for 6.1 doesn't have the calendar, the iOS 7 simulator surprisingly has the calendar installed.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem.